# javaee.jar and javax.ejb.jar in JBOSS 6?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, jar, jboss

My question is pretty simple. Where locates jars `javaee.jar` and `javax.ejb.jar`  in JBOSS 6.X?

I'm using `JBOSS-6.3.2` and search those jar at the location `jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\lib`.

I'm finding `javaee.jar` and `javax.ejb.jar` JARs to add them to my JUnit Project `lib`.

But till now I failed to find those JARs

Comment: Do you need these so that you can compile your application? They do not exist in this form in JBoss EAP 6.x or WildFly.

Comment: I need to add those to my JUNIT project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a jar for this purpose in Maven Central at [jboss-javaee-all-6.0-3.0.3.Final.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-all-6.0/3.0.3.Final/jboss-javaee-all-6.0-3.0.3.Final.jar).

This includes the classes that would be included in any notional `javax.ejb.jar`.